# extracting zip with long name

Tags: vbscript, zip

I've found out (on the hard way) that if I try to unzip a file (using shell application) with a long zip name, I receive an error: "system cannot find the file specified".
I've managed to bypass that by renaming the zip file and after the extraction renaming it back, the problem is that in order to rename I need to move the file and then move it back, which takes too long for every zip.

Is there an alternative to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying functions support filenames up to 32,000 characters long. However programs only allocate 520 bytes (260 characters) of memory to store filenames.

IF explorer can handle it prefacing filenames with `\\?\` turns off legal file name checking (max length 260 characters, max length of a part 255 characters).

CMD supports `\\?\` syntax.